# Zoom and highline features from wkt openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, postgis

I have a polygon with WKT format :
`POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))`

i want zoom to this feature and make it highline ,can anyone give me the example?

Comment: What did you already try? Add you actual code.

Comment: Thank u ,i did it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , it work for me

```
function zoomByWKT(wkt){

   var feature=new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(wkt));   
   selectVector.removeAllFeatures();
   selectVector.addFeatures([feature]);
   vectorHightlight.activate();
   vectorHightlight.select(feature);
   vectorHightlight.deactivate();
   // zoom
   map.zoomToExtent(selectVector.features[0].geometry.getBounds());

}
```

VectorHightline is the select control , it will make u features highline by select it .